# Best way to approach group removal in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

The provided code is part of a C# Windows Forms application for a student housing app. It includes a GroceryFormRemove form that allows users to manage a shared grocery list. The form consists of UI elements like text boxes, buttons, and a list box. When the user clicks the "Add Product" button, the entered product details are collected, and the total price is calculated. The product details, along with the creator's name, are displayed in the list box. The total price is divided equally among other users except for the current user, and their names with respective prices are added to the list box. The "Product Remove" button allows the removal of selected items from the list box, excluding the creator's name, product details, and divider line. Additionally, the code includes event handlers for various sidebar buttons, enabling navigation to different sections of the student housing app.

What I want it to do is to automatically delete the respective creator name and product details after the four people names (paying users) have been removed. Now I know how to do this if there is just one payment iteration but the problem occurs if I add multiple items. Please let me know if something doesn't make sense.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Student_Housing_App
{
    public partial class GroceryFormRemove : Form
    {
        private List<double> productPrices = new List<double>();
        private List<string> peopleNames = new List<string> { "Joep", "Martin", "Bob", "Lute", "John" };

        private string userName;
        private User currentUser;

        public GroceryFormRemove(User user)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.currentUser = user;
        }

        private void AddProductbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Set up for variables
            string product = ProductNametbx.Text;
            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantitytbx.Text);
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(ProductPricetbx.Text);
            double totalprice = quantity * price;

            string productDetails = $"Product: {product}   Quantity: {quantity} - Price: €{totalprice}";

            double dividedPrice = totalprice / 5;

            // Insertion of currentuser and product details
            Grocerieslbx.Items.Add($"Creator: {currentUser.userName}");

            Grocerieslbx.Items.Add(productDetails);

            // A for loop to only add a specific number of iterations depending on peopleNames
            // list length and to exclude the currentUser's name
            for (int i = 0; i < peopleNames.Count; i++)
            {
                string personName = peopleNames[i];
                if (personName != currentUser.userName)
                {
                    Grocerieslbx.Items.Add($"{personName} - €{dividedPrice}");
                }
            }
        }

        private void ProductRemovebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Grocerieslbx.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                int selectedIndex = Grocerieslbx.SelectedIndex;

                // If statement to disallow the removal of currentUser's name, product details, and divided line (----)
                if (Grocerieslbx.Items[selectedIndex].ToString().StartsWith(currentUser.userName)
                    || Grocerieslbx.Items[selectedIndex].ToString().StartsWith("Product"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You cannot remove this item.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Grocerieslbx.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an item to remove.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```